# Modular exponentiation relatively slow in Pascal

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, primes, pascal

I have been developing program in Pascal for generating large primes. After many tries I have successfully (I hope) implemented modular exponentiation using the Montgomery exponentiation algorithm. It is way faster than [right-to-left binary method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) from my tests. I used algorithms from the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography chapter 14](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf), because I used http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/100digitbigintcalculator.htm for checking mistakes and it is basically the only online calculator for big numbers.

Modular exponentiation of like 100 digit numbers (base,exp,mod) takes roughly 300ms compared to even the javascript version. This feels slow. I have tried using profiling my code and fixed a couple of bottlenecks but it is still pretty slow imo compared to the javascript implementation. Profiling shows that most of the calls are used for basic multiplication (vynasob function) and subtraction (odecti function), but I dont see how those can be made faster. Is it because I represent numbers as base 10 in array? I dont think it is that much of a problem. Here is my code https://github.com/Honzaik/PPrime/blob/master/pprime.lpr If someone was that kind and skimmed through if you find some weird stuff that might help. The code is in Czech sadly tho. But the important functions are:

```
isPrime = Rabin-Miller

montExp = Montgomery Exponentiation

montMult = Montgomery Multiplication

secti = addition

odecti = subtraction

vynasob = multiplication

vydel = division

modulus = modulus
```

As I said, I represent numbers as array in base 10. eg 10587 = [7,8,5,0,1]

Thank you for your responses

Comment: side note, you should increase base to maximum possible

Comment: Why Montgomery multiplication? For such relatively small numbers (100 digits is small, in that context), a simple binary exponentiation is much easier. And indeed, base 2^32 would be a little better.

Comment: @Sopel i thought about that. i will try it out!

Comment: @RudyVelthuis do you mean exponentiation? I used montgomery exponentiation because according to my testing it was faster than the right-to-left binary method, i implemented it also as function - "modular_pow" but it is slower. i will try out the bigger bases. but i still dont think it should make that much of a difference

Comment: I actually meant mutliplication (Montgomery modular multiplication, which is only useful on huge values). I confused it with modular exponentiation, which is, IME, quite fast using plain right to left exponentiation, especially for such relatively small values. But using a base of 10 would slow things down considerably.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis ok, i understand. i will try using 2^32 (longint) as base!

Comment: FWIW, take a look at my BigInteger implementation: https://github.com/rvelthuis/BigNumbers. That is for Delphi, but it should be possible to make it work in FreePascal too (see http://www.rvelthuis.de/programs/bigintegers.html#fpc).

Comment: You could also use 10^8 or 10^9 instead of 2^32 as base to use most of the integer data type. Then conversion for printing would be simplified.

Comment: @LutzL i think im not gonna be able to to use 10^8 even, because the in the algorithm i have to once multiply three numbers in those bases and pascal's biggest datatype is 18446744073709551615 so i will have to use like 3rd root of that. still good. or am i mistaken?

Comment: @honzaik: You will have to use a type that can have multiple "limbs" or "bigits" or whatever you call them. Multiplication can be done over multiple integers. It is what most BigInteger implementations do. Find a good book about this, e.g. Knuth's "The Art Of Computer Programming" (esp. Vol 2). You just need dynamic arrays, but AFAIK, FreePascal (I assume that is what you are using) has those.

Comment: @honzaik: I tried to take a look at your code, but the fact that almost every identifier is in Czech makes it terribly hard to understand. I myself am Dutch and live in Germany, but have never used anything else but English identifiers. Makes sharing code a lot easier, especially these days.

Comment: @honzaik: You have to multiply 3 numbers? Usually in modular multiplication you need to multiply two numbers, and maybe add in another.

Comment: @JamesKPolk im multiplying 3 base numbers in normal multiplication algorithm, also in a division.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis thank you for your advice! i quickly implemented bigger base (2097151) and it is way faster now (from 300ms to 8ms). not using montgomery algorithms. I will try them out when i have time and will compare it! i have checked your library many times but i always got lazy following everything, there is a lot of stuff. good job. btw i sent you an email like a month ago and you didnt reply. its not relevant now, but just a notice that you might wanna check it/update it on your website

Comment: btw sorry for my czech/english code. i use it for a school project so I sometimes interchange the languages, i didnt really plan on releasing it on the internet :P

Answer (score 1):

The answer/advice for improvement is to use biggest base you can. i changed base 10 to base 2097151 and 300ms became 8ms. thank you everyone in comments for advices